# Dummy variables with dummyVars() - return to original columns

Tags: r, machine-learning, categorical-encoding

For building a machine learning model I used `dummyVars()` function to create the dummy variables for building a model.

```
dummies_model <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data=input_data)
input_data2 <- predict(dummies_model, input_data)
```

I am now deploying the model but I want to return to the user the table with the original columns (not the factor columns). Is there a function that returns the original columns and not the dummy ones created by `dummyVars()`?

Comment: This link will provide the answer: https://amunategui.github.io/dummyVar-Walkthrough/. In essence, just doing something like data.frame(input_data2) should work. Try print(data.frame(input_data2)) to print the dummies in the R console.

Comment: Not sure if I was clear or did not understand your answer. I already have the model with dummies. Now I want to return to the original columns of the dataset, for example sex: male and female, turned into two binary columns: male and female, now I want to go back to having one column with a factor of two levels.

Comment: Don't you have that information in your input_data? That's where you would find your original variables.

Comment: Yes I do, but since some of the observations are removed, either because of NA, outliers etc, I would not be able to use the original input data if I don't have a unique row identifier.